# scrollRectToVisible for a UITableView doesn't always take section headers into account

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView in which I'm using section headers. The contents of the table view are text form fields. I have a "next/previous" control on the keyboard toolbar, and I use `scrollRectToVisible` to scroll the form field to make particular rows visible. `next` works fine-- the field ends up immediately above the keyboard. I'm having a problem with `previous` in some cases, however. In some cases, with fields near the top of the table view, `scrollRectToVisible` appears to not take into account the section headers. After `scrollRectToVisible` operates, the view is not fully visible -- rather it is occluded by the section header.

For example, in the following, this is immediately after pressing `Previous` and `scrollRectToVisible` finishes. The cursor is positioned where the arrow is pointing. The phone number field is occluded by the "Phone" section header.

[image]

I have tried a) first getting the index path of the row in question, and b) then using scrollToRow. Oddly that's not always working for me. The row I need isn't always visible after.

Suggestions?